# Найти значение атрибута в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как можно достать значение value элемента `data-property`, которое находится в
`this.$()[0].attributes`.

[image]

Делаю так:

`var property = $(this.getDomElement()).attr("data-property");`

Но значение приходит `s:SomeProperty`.

Подскажите, как получить значение `SomeProperty` без `s:`?

Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте так: `this.$()[0].attributes.getNamedItem("data-property")`

Comment: возвращает все что есть `data-property`, а если взять `this.$()[0].attributes.getNamedItem("data-property").value` - то буде тоже самое значение с `s:`

Comment: А если вместо value сделать nodeValue

Comment: тоже самое + ругается на то, что nodeValue is deprecated

Comment: по поводу deprecated [это не так][1], попробуйте: `this.$()[0].attributes.getNamedItem("property").nodeValue`


  [1]:  http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/met_nodemap_getnameditem.asp

Comment: не помогло

Comment: @Telsystems, раз не помогает, значит нужно больше подробностей, например, код, из которого вытаскивается значение :)